# Number of Days in a Year with Consecutive Perfect Squares

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Given:

Number of Days in a normal Year

To Do:

Express it in two different ways utilizing Squares of consecutive positive numbers.

Comment: Thx for the edit

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Way

> $13^2+14^2=169+196=365$

Second Way

> $10^2+11^2+12^2=100+121+144=365$

Answer (score 2):

Also

> In a leap year (normally every 4th year)
>
>  $8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2 + 11^2 = 64 + 81 + 100 + 121 = 366$

And

> In 1752 (a leap year but definitely abnormal) 11 days were removed from the calendar, so there were only 355 days.
>
>  $5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2 = 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81 + 100 = 355$

Comment: but it is a normal year... (ie 365 days) +1 tho!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton the question did ask for a "normal" year, and I tried in the first part to get round that because a leap year is normal, except for `2100` etc. In the  second part I have no excuse – I just wanted to post the discovery!

Comment: true, https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/year.html lol

Comment: Puzzles need to be enjoyed ...not dissected..good extraneous info..normal is most of the time..if you ask normal person he would say what most people would expect